# private static variable in struct

Tags: swift

in this example getInstance is public so it makes sense to be accessible but the private variable was accessible as well, why?

```
public class SingleObject {

    public struct Static {

        private static var object: SingleObject?

        public static func getObject() -> SingleObject {
            if (object == nil) {
                object = SingleObject()
            }
            return object!
        }
    }

}

SingleObject.Static.object //why private is accessible here?

SingleObject.Static.getObject()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `private` access modifier makes a declaration private to the file and not to the class or struct. That sounds a little weird, I know, but it's how it's implemented in swift.

The other 2 access modifiers are:

- internal: accessible in the current module only
- public: accessible from anywhere

Suggested reading: [Access Control](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH41-XID_29)

Comment: any explanation for this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713835/compiler-forcing-self-inside-static-method-of-a-function-while-using-dispatch-sy

Answer (score 6):

As of Swift 3, the example code no longer compiles.  A new modifier called `fileprivate` was added and works the way `private` used to work (i.e. it can be seen by anything else in the same file).

`private` in Swift 3 and 4 now works more like you would expect it to - in Swift 3, it can only be accessed within the context it was declared in, while in Swift 4 it can also be accessed from extensions to that type (but only if they're in the same file).

Answer (score 1):

The private keyword means that the variable is only accessible **within the same file** not within the same class.

You are accessing the property from within the same file, which is why it is working. Try doing it from a different file and you will see that it is not accessible.

Comment: Sorry to downvote, but this is incorrect. The fileprivate keyword will refer to a variable only accessible in the same file. But the private keywork will work inside of that class or struct. For example, an extension to a class will be able to access it from another file.

Comment: @AlecO The curse of a moving language. My answer was correct at time of writing, and actually answered the question.

Comment: @AlecO Swift 4: `private` keyword will not work if you are trying to access it from an extension at another file